# Can i do union using JOIN keyword?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
select 'A' as ctable, a.coll1, a.coll2, a.coll3 from TABLE_A a
union all
select 'B' as ctable, b.coll1, b.coll2, b.coll3 from TABLE_B b
```

Output:

```
CTABLE  COLL1   COLL2   COLL3
A       01      abc     bac
A       02      das     asd
A       03      eas     sae
B       01      bad     dab
B       04      bmn     nmb
B       05      cas     sac
```

Here, i want to same output using JOIN. Coll1 is the primary key for both tables. Table can be empty or data can be same but output will be all rows from both tables.

Comment: Why a `JOIN`? Seems to be almost a perfect case for `UNION ALL`.

Comment: i want to skip redundant of SQL

Comment: What do you mean with "redundant"? to get the same result with a JOIN, you will need more code than a UNION ALL, not less, and the resulting code will be less efficient, less readable, ...

Comment: If it's just the duplication of column names you want to avoid then you could do something like `SELECT ctable, coll1, coll2, coll3 FROM (SELECT 'A' AS ctable, * FROM table_a UNION ALL SELECT 'B' AS ctable, * FROM table_b)` but that relies on *all* column names matching in the two tables. You're probably better off with the simple statement you already have.

Answer (score 0):

This might not give the same performance as an UNION but I think this is what you are looking for

You need to create a view:

```
create view mutex as 
select i
from (select 0
union
select 1)sq (i)
```

Now you can use this view to get your desired results as:

```
select coalesce(a.A,b.B),coalesce(a.coll1,b.coll1),coalesce(a.coll2,b.coll2),coalesce(a.coll3,b.coll3)
from mutex
left join TABLE_A as a on i =0
left join TABLE_B as b on i =1
```

Note: Instead of a mutex view, you can also use a table that will have these 2 rows